# SQLite : obtain current week

Tags: sqlite, date

I'm trying to obtain the current week for date comparison in SQLite.
I have no problem for last month, last year, today, yesterday... but don't find the solution to have the current week.

I tried lot of things like:

```
SELECT tastings.* FROM tastings   
WHERE (DATE(tastings.date) > DATE('now','weekday 1','+ 7 days'))
```

Can you help me ? Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean the week of the year? As in %W week of year: 00-53 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is stored inside the `tastings.date` column? Note that SQLite does not have “timestamp” type affinity, so probably you store Text (some representation of the date) or integer (julian day, epoch…)

All time and date functions expect a valid [time string](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) and convert that time string to another string format. If `tastings.date` contains a week number then use:

```
AND cast(tastings.date AS TEXT) = strftime('%W','now')
```

Answer (score 9):

This code gives you the week number where the first day of week is monday. It also works well for last and first weeks of the year.

```
strftime('%W', 'now', 'localtime', 'weekday 0', '-6 days')
```

Comment: you are a life-saver. i was using `DATE('now','localtime','weekday 1','-7 days')` in PROD, which made the app go crazy.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you want compare 2 date, Assume you have a table named `_testTbl` and have 3 column `_id INTEGER`, `_name TEXT`, `_recordDate TEXT`

you want name that record this week
you can use below code:

```sql
SELECT * FROM _testTbl
WHERE _recordDate > datetime('now', 'start of day', 'weekday 6', '-7 day')
```

note that this week start by saturday (sunday 0, monday 1, ..., saturday 7)
this t-sql means:

[`datetime`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) is a sqlite date and time function.

- first parameter is given time: `'now'` means the current time.
- second parameter take the time to start of day.
- third parameter take time to the *next* weekday number (in this case, saturday).
- fourth parameter take time to start of week

Answer (score 1):

This helps me to compare the 2 dates using the week of the year.

```
AND ( strftime('%W', tastings.date) = strftime('%W', 'now') )
```

Thanks you.